# Get json casing in backend

Tags: servicestack

Is there a method I can use that gets the casing that is used when ServiceStack converts DTO properties into Json response?

For instance a backend model property name `MyProperty` becomes json property `myProperty` and `ABCProperty` becomes `abcProperty` and `My_PROPERTY` becomes `my_property` (i think I got those right anyway).

I am having some issues lining up the casing from front end to backend in my code.  Is there a public method that I can use to get the proper casing?

Comment: I think the short answer is no. How is the function suppose to know if you want the first three or two characters lower case the upper. You could probably write a quick function using strtoupper and/or strtolower(those are PHP functions, I don't know the java off the top of my head).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by how is function meant to know if letters are upper case.  I am trying to recreate logic that already exists when servicestack converts to camelcase.  SS seems to have it's own logical way of doing it so I assumed there is a routine somewhere that handles it but I am unsure where it is or I could copy paste that code.  Really I just need to know the exct logic SS follows so I can re-create it but I figured there must already be method for this.

Answer (score 1):

`ToCamelCase()` method has behavior I needed.